# Delete parallel lines to calculate total network length

Tags: qgis, vector, network, parallel-lines

I have problem with parallel lines in QGIS. I want to delete lines, which have common courses with others (expample of lines is in the picture below) [image].

Context: The lines are network-lines and to calculate the total lenght of the network's roads/ways I need to be able to ignore the duplicate lines.

Comment: What do you want to produce given those example lines? Just remove one of the pair of very parallel lines, or also remove the section of the line that has a section parallel to the other two? How would you numerically define two lines to be "parallel"? Are they always going to be straight or might they be parallel lines along curves like coastlines or winding roads?

Comment: In general i want to calculate the total lenght of network, therefore i want to somehow  ignore the duplicate parts of lines

Comment: I'm asking about the specific example in your image. For those three lines there, what output do you want? If you can edit your Q and show that output that would help enormously. You also do need to think about what makes lines "parallel" since its unlikely that two features will be precisely mathematically parallel.

Comment: You can e.g. provide a (subset) of your data/link to a publicly available data-source that helps to reproduce your issue. In addition provide something like a drawing that explains what you want